# if-else optimization: sanity check over multitype object

Tags: python

I have an object X that could be a dataframe or None

I'd like to check if X is empty or None.

```
if x:
 # do something
```

doesn't work.

I have this:

```
if isinstance(x, pd.DataFrame):
    if x.empty:
        status = False
    else:
        status = True
elif x is None:
    status = False
else:
    status = True
```

But it seems optimizable.
Do you have any advice?

Comment: it is not optimizable

Comment: Note that the proper optimization is usually to avoid x being None in the first place.

Comment: With isinstance use and and check if x is empty there itself it will remove one of your condition

Answer (score 1):

Simple `try-except` should do:

```
status = True
x = f() # f may return a dataframe or None
try:
    status = not x.empty # x.empty returns bool
except:
    print("x is either None or NOT a dataframe")
    status = x is not None
```

If you are not sure if `x` may be an object (not of type `pd.DataFrame`) which may have the attribute `empty` as well, you can change the condition inside your `try`:

```
status = not x.empty and isinstance(x, pd.DataFrame)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally write the code like the block I wrote below. It accomplishes what you would like to do and removes nested statements keeping it readable and its purpose straightforward for another maintainer.

```
status = True
if x is None:
    status = False
elif isinstance(x, pd.DataFrame) and x.empty:
    status = False
```

If x is guaranteed to be a Dataframe when it is not None you could remove the isinstance part of the elif check.

Comment: "True and .." is unnecessary. True and A is A.

Answer (score 1):

What we often do is start from a base case and only re-assign values if some condition is met. This avoids an additional (and often repeated) else-clause. In your case you could write:

```py
status = True

if x is None or isinstance(x, pd.DataFrame) and x.empty:
    status = False
```

Note that efficiency-wise the difference is minimal/non-existent (we still check whether x is None AND (if it isn't) whether it is a DataFrame and whether it is empty), but it is more concise and, **arguably**, more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Approach it from the specific to the general:

```
status = isinstance(x, pd.DataFrame) and not x.empty or x is not None
```